# String ordering in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, lexicographic

I noticed that in Python we have:

- `'0' < 'A' < 'a'`
- `'0' < '00'`

As far as I understand, there are multiple **possible** **lexicographical** orderings of characters and strings, so I assume this is **one type** specifically.

Does this **lexicographic ordering** have a name? and is it in any way specific to Python?

Comment: The exact name you are looking for is [Unicode](https://home.unicode.org/basic-info/faq/).

Comment: Thanks @usr2564301, what about string length? Are shorter strings < longer strings?

Comment: Yes. Try it. Also logically: *any* character is "greater than" no character. There is nothing weird in this in Python, it's a generally accepted concept.